# Plotly Histogram nbinx does not provide the right number of bins in Python

Tags: python, histogram, plotly

With the following code I get 15 bins instead of 20 as expected.

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.offline import plot
from plotly.graph_objs import Histogram

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AntoineGautier/Data/master/tmp.txt')

plot(dict(data=[Histogram(x=df.ws, nbinsx=20)],
          layout=dict(xaxis=dict(dtick=1), bargap=0.25)
         ))
```

Comment: I don't use pandas, but maybe layout is overriding - your largest value is 14.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually a description error. The way to do this would be to set `autobinx` to False, then use the `xbins` parameter to specify the start, end, and size of bins as a proxy for setting the number of bins you want.

Comment: Perfect example of unneeded complexity adding to user's cognitive load.